Merging overlapping rasters using ArcGIS Pro
I am trying to merge multiple rasters into one raster. I have tried multiple methods, including:

Importing them into a file geodatabase raster, merge tool, made a mosaic dataset, but none of these have worked.
As you can see from the image, the rasters seem to be overlayed onto each other.
How do I display all of the rasters as one, without them overlapping each other?

Since Mosaic Dataset is the way to go with ArcGIS tools, the problem must be with the data. Pick two neighbors and provide all the extent and coordinate reference details in the Question.

I would use "Mosaic to new raster (data management)" and pay very close attention to every parameter input. What specifically is wrong with the result? Is it just a rendering issue and zooming in shows the expected data?
